# stuck transaction despite high fee - will it eventually be forgotten?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made this transaction a few days ago with a normal fee, but it's still stuck.
https://blockchain.info/tx/461df29d7a923491e24688a79d902fb027929d1b3b57fa6e272015a9250394bc

Any suggestions how long this will take? Is the bitcoin network falling apart? For how long will my wallet broadcast it? Will it eventually be forgotten?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it has yet to be 'processed' by a miner yet. I can't tell you an actual definite timetable besides the usual 3days - 3+ weeks. It could clear sooner, but it just hasn't been cataloged and processed into and solved in the next block.

Comment: how do I know if my wallet (JAXX) keeps broadcasting it?

Comment: @Nickpick If you're talking about how you will know the progression of the chain I don't know about that. You can also check into the other thread this was marked as a duplicate of.